Debugging Linux Kernel using KGDBOE failing to connect to the host
I am trying to debug remotely the kernel of an Nvidia Orin target using kgdboe, In the target side using this command to start debugging.
sudo insmod /lib/modules/5.10.120-as6-l4t-r35.4.ga/extra/kgdboe.ko kallsyms_lookup_name_address=0x$(sudo cat /proc/kallsyms | grep 'T kallsyms_lookup_name' | awk '{print $1}') device_name=enP5p4s0

There is this following output in the kernel messages:
sudo dmesg --follow

[   53.835617] kgdboe: Successfully initialized. Use the following gdb command to attach:
[   53.835623]  target remote udp:***.***.***.***:31337

Then in the Host using gdb-multiarch there is this following error:
(gdb) target remote udp:***.***.***.***:31337 warning: The remote protocol may be unreliable over UDP. Some events may be lost, rendering further debugging impossible. Remote debugging using udp:***.***.***.***:31337 Ignoring packet error, continuing... Remote replied unexpectedly to 'vMustReplyEmpty': timeout
I tried setting a longer timeout and setting arm architecture in the gdb but did not work.
I also tried adding the following to the kernel boot arguments:
kgdbwait kgdbcon kgdboe=@***.***.***.***/24


Are you on the same subnet as the system?

@stark , Yes, I can ping the IP and also ssh into the target.

Neither of those things mean you are on the same subnet.
